# cocos2d sprite current postion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I have class that contains CCsprite and Im using that class in the gamelayer to walk around. I wanted to get current position of the Node so I called,

```
NSLog(@"%d",myClass.sprite.position.x);
NSLog(@"%d",myClass.sprite.position.y);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"%d",myClass.position.x);
NSLog(@"%d",myClass.position.y);
```

But it only returns 0 value in console. Im I dealing with wrong thing here?

Comment: What type of class is myClass? What's its super class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` member variable is of type `CGFloat`, so the correct flag for it's members (`x` and `y`, both floats) is `%f`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `NSLog("%@", NSStringFromPoint(self.position));` or `NSLog("%@", NSStringFromPoint(sprite.position));` depending on where you call this from.